# How to get Contact Groups into Contact Manager Sample App?

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract, accounts

I am running the Contact Manager sample app from the Android SDK. When I add a contact to my Gmail account, it gets added as an 'invisible contact'. I am assuming this is because I am not telling the contact which 'group' it should be assigned to. I have been looking around the internet for a few days and have come up empty handed.

What I really want to do is add the contact to the Contact Account that I select and have the contact associated with a Contact Group within the selected Gmail Account, so the contact's info will be displayed in the user's contacts.

Comment: Is there a reason I can't get an answer to this question anywhere? Am I missing something basic, or is there no good answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Android are you targeting? You are of course aware that the Contacts API changed radically in 2.x...

I hit this exact problem of invisible contacts, but only on 1.x. I found the solution was to add to the built-in "My Contacts" group :

```
// Add to the My Contacts group
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(GroupMembership.PERSON_ID, contact.mAndroidId); 
values.put(GroupMembership.GROUP_ID, 1); // 1 is always the ID of the built-in "My Contacts" group 
activity.getContentResolver().insert(GroupMembership.CONTENT_URI,values);
```

If you want to add to a specific user-defined group rather than My Contacts you will need to fish the right GROUP_ID out of the [`Contacts.Groups`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Groups.html) table.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work with the new ContactsContract API, you can add this to the ContentProviderOperation list:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, 1)
            .build());
```